# Increase full date by a number of days in php

Tags: php, date

I'm wanting to increase the current full date, (according to ISO 8601 format):

Something like
`2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00` to
`2004-03-12T15:19:21+00:00` (increased by 1 month).

Need some ideas and help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$yourDate = '2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00';
$offset = '+1 month';

$newDate = date('c', strtotime($yourDate . ' ' . $offset));
```

`strtotime` converts your ISO 8601-formatted date to a timestamp, plus the offset you want. Then, the `'c'` parameter in `date()` formats the timestamp back to ISO 8601.

Comment: note: doing month math is HIGHLY unreliable. `2001-01-31 + 1 month` is actually March 2nd

Comment: It also understands `"now + 5 month"`, i.e. `"now"` as placeholder for "now". ;)